# すでにある静的ライブラリを新たに生成する静的ライブラリにインクルードする CMAKE の書き方

Tags: cmake

新たに生成する静的ライブラリ(例えばaaa.a)に、すでに生成してある静的ライブラリ(例えばbbb.a)をインクルードするにはどうすればよいでしょうか…

How can we include another static library has crated already (like bbb.a) to new static library (like aaa.a) ?

Comment: もしかしたら、これらが参考になるかも。[How to group multiple library targets into one in CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56568570/9014308), [Combining several static libraries into one using CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37924383/9014308), [\[CMake\] Combining several static libraries into a single static library](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2014-August/058231.html), [\[CMake\] Combining several static libraries into a single static library](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2014-August/058235.html)

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。https://qiita.com/fault/items/2a3201fc697a2e537906 なページを見つけました。これを CMAKE でやるとどうなるのかを探しているのですが…なかなか(笑)

Comment: どの説明もソースから作るのが前提ですが、単にライブラリを指定してみるとか？ `add_library(aaa STATIC bbb.a)` みたいに。